# Win32 programming child window does not have exit button

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi I am writing a Win32 Windows program. I created a child window with the following command

```
case ID_VIEW_CARVIEW:

            carViewHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"Edit", L"Edit",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_BORDER,
                000, 00, 656, 519, hWnd, (HMENU)NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
            SetWindowLongPtr(carViewHwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)CarViewWndProc);
```

However, this child windows has two problems:

1. It does not have a "close" button on the top right.
2. It always stay on top of all windows on my desktop top.

How can I change it?

Comment: You are creating a standard [Edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-controls), not a popup window, so of course it is not going to have a Close button on it. Why would you expect an Edit control to have a close button? And why are you specifying `WS_EX_TOPMOST`, `WS_POPUP`, and `WS_CAPTION` for a *child* control? Those only apply to top-level popup windows. If you want a free-floating Edit control, you need to make it a child of a free-floating popup window that is its parent.

Comment: I am new to win32 programming. I just want to free-floating windows with a paint area and the standward close, minimize button. Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: So, then why are you creating an Edit control? For what you are asking, you need to call `RegisterClass/Ex()` to register a custom class name, and then you can call `CreateWindow/Ex()` using that class name. See [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) on MSDN, particularly the section on [Creating a Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/creating-a-window).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It does not have a "close" button on the top right.

You need set [WS_SYSMENU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles) flag for dwStyle parameter to have a window menu on its title bar.

> 2. It always stay on top of all windows on my desktop top.

Because you define [WS_EX_TOPMOST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) style: "The window should be placed above all non-topmost windows and should stay above them, even when the window is deactivated."